# Find the size of a array without the standard library(in c)

Tags: c, libc

I want to find the size of an array without the standard library(libc). While looking at the musl source code I couldnt find where sizeof() was located.

Comment: `sizeof` is a language keyword, it's implemented by the compiler

Comment: Furthermore, `sizeof` is not a function. You can use `sizeof variable` or `sizeof(type)`.